# Android app crash.. intent flag?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-notifications, flags

My app has been getting some crashes lately, and I'm wondering if it could be due to the flags on the intents.

When the crash happens, the app is closed I believe, during a rest timer. A fragment is opened, then the user can click start, which starts a 90 second countdown timer. The user gets a notification when the timer ends, which when clicked should bring the user back to the open fragment. The error doesn't happen very often, I can't recreate it every time.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4913)
at com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.Workouts.Week1Mon.showNotification(Week1Mon.java:171)
at com.bestworkouts.sheikoworkout.Workouts.Week1Mon$1.onFinish(Week1Mon.java:147)
at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

and here is the notification where the error is(it says the error is at Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyWorkout.class):

```
public void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sheikoicon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Sheiko Rest Timer");
    builder.setContentText("Rest timer is up, start your set!");
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyWorkout.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getContext());
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyWorkout.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Where I start the countdown timer and call showNotification:

```
private void start() {
    cancel();
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtViewRest.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " Secs");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            txtViewRest.setText("Start!");
            showNotification();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with my FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your code seems to be running inside a `CountDownTimer`, could it be that `getActivity()` is returning `null` because it is being called from another thread?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm pretty new to android, but I added the code where I start the timer and call showNotification method if that helps

Comment: Like @MohanadMohie said, you're within your CountDownTimer's context, so getActivity() will return null in this case. You should pass the activity context into the showNotification() method

Comment: I just confirmed it. I could reproduce the error by opening the `Activity` that holds the `Fragment`, then closing it before the `CountDownTimer` is finished. That way, `getActivity()` always returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is running on another thread, if by the time the `CountDownTimer` is finished the `Fragment` has been closed for any reason, both `getActivity()` and `getContext()` will return `null`.

You should save your context in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate`:

```
private Context context;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context= getContext();

    // Your code here

}
```

Then use it in inside your `showNotification()` method:

```
public void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sheikoicon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Sheiko Rest Timer");
    builder.setContentText("Rest timer is up, start your set!");
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWorkout.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyWorkout.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortunately still getting the crash. I'm able to reproduce it now by pressing the back button thanks to you which is huge help. I have done like you showed to no avail. The main class for the page checks the intent passed to it, depending on the intent, it creates a viewpager with different pages. Each page has a separate class that populates the viewpager with data. It seems to only crash if I hit the back button, if I navigate to other places in the app, or close it down, it works properly

Comment: I beleive the application crashes now because you are trying to call `TextView.setText()` while the `Fragment` is destroyed, which is a different error than the previous one.

Comment: the stacktrace still says java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: I tried the code several times while closing the application before the timer finishes, and every time the Notification showed with no errors. Try to confirm that `context` is not null when you first initialize it, and that you did not forget removing `getContext()` or `getActivity()` from the code. I would suggest updating the question with your new code.

Comment: Okay thank you I will try this tomorrow after work. Thanks again